# Как отследить в шаблоне если 3 цикла не нашли друга подписчика и подписку

Tags: django

```
        {% for profile in user_list %}
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                <img class="mr-3" src="{{ profile.avatar.url | default:'media/default.jpg' }}" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="100" height="100">
                <h5>{{ profile.firstname}} {{ profile.lastname}}</h5>
                <h5>{{ profile.sity }}</h5>
                <h5>{{ profile.blood_type }}</h5>
                <!--ПРОВЕРЯЕТ В СПИСКЕ ДРУЗЕЙ ОН ВАШ ДРУГ-->
                {% for chek_friends in friends_list %}
                    {% if chek_friends.ot_user_friends == profile %}
                        <form method="post" action='search/{{ chek_friends.id }}' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button type="submit" name="del_friendsw" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Удалить из друзей</button>  
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

                
                <!--ПРОВЕРЯЕТ В СПИСКЕ ПОДПИСЧИКОВ ОН ВАШ ПОДПИСЧИК-->
                {% for chek_follower in subscribers_list %}
                    {% if chek_follower.userss == profile %}
                        <form method="post" action='search/{{ chek_follower.id }}' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button type="submit" name="go_friends" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Принять в друзья</button>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

                
                <!--ПРОВЕРЯЕТ В СПИСКЕ ВАШИХ ПОДПИСОК ВЫ НА НЕГО ПОДПИСАНЫ-->
                {% for chek_subscriptions in subscribers_list %}
                    {% if chek_subscriptions.ot_user_subscribers == profile %}
                        <form method="post" action='search/{{ chek_subscriptions.id }}' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button type="submit" name="cancel_subscription" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Отменить заявку</button>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}       
                {% endfor %}
                    
            </a>
       {% endfor%}
```

**В шаблоне django 3 цикла проверяют User мой друг, подписчик или я на него подписан если ничего из этого не подходит как отследить это**

Comment: Перенесите заголовок в вопрос.